# react-hot-loader not updating after changes in styled-components css in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, styled-components, react-hot-loader

I am building a simple SPA using "create-react-app". The problem I am having is, "react-hot-loader" is not working when CSS is updated from "styled-components". It works with normal CSS file but doesn't work with styled components. I did eject from create-react-app.

This is my packag.json

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.3",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.4.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^4.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "styled-components": "^2.2.1",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.8.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.2.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": ["src/**/*.{js,jsx}"],
    "setupFiles": ["<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"],
    "testMatch": ["<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)", "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["web.js", "js", "json", "web.jsx", "jsx", "node"]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": ["react-app"]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

This is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';

import './theme/globalStyle';

// const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppContainer>
    <App />
  </AppContainer>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./App', () => {
    const App = require('./App').default;
    ReactDOM.render(
      <AppContainer>
        <App />
      </AppContainer>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
  });
}
```

My app.js with routes.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Works from './components/Works';
import FourOhFour from './components/FourOhFour';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/works" component={Works} />
            <Route component={FourOhFour} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I also added `'react-hot-loader/patch',` in entry of webpack.config.dev.js and added query for plugins in webpack.config.dev.js

```
// Process JS with Babel.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        query: {
          // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
          // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
          // directory for faster rebuilds.
          cacheDirectory: true,
          plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel']
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your package your json try asing this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
```

and add this dependency using

```
nom install webpack-dev-server --hot
```

Then start your application using **npm start**